# mongoose returning ObjectParameterError() while saving to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a restaurant schema and a reviews schema....whenever I am trying to include a review in the mongoose database using create() method it is generating error as:

> ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object,
>   got very costly place at new ObjectParameterError
>   (/workspace/groomIDE-setup123/restaurants/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/objectParameter.js:25:11)

my schemas are as follows:

```
var restSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    review: String,
    image: String,
    reviews:[{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Review"
    }
    ]
})
var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author:{
        id:{
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"User"
        },
        username:String
    },
    review:String
});
```

The Route for creating a new review and displaying it is as follows:

```
app.post("/restaurants/:id/reviews",(req,res)=>{
    Restaurant.findById(req.params.id,(err,foundRestaurant)=>{
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
        Review.create(req.body.comment,(err,newReview)=>{
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else{
            newReview.author.id=req.user._id;
            newReview.author.username=req.user.username;
            newReview.save();
            foundRestaurant.reviews.push(newReview);
            foundRestaurant.save();
            // res.redirect("/restaurants/"+req.params.id);
            }
        })  
    })
});
app.get("/restaurants/:id",(req,res)=>{
    Restaurant.findById(req.params.id).populate("reviews").exec((err,foundRestaurant)=>{
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else{
            res.render("show",{restaurant:foundRestaurant});
            }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose `create()` function need to get values matching the schema.
You can read more about it here : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create
Try to define your new newReview object and then pushing it into foundRestaurant.reviews array like so:

set new review object:

`const newReview={
   author.id:req.user._id,
   username:req.user.username,
};`

create and save it:

`Review.create(newReview);`

and then push it into the Restaurant.reviews array:

`foundRestaurant.reviews.push(newReview);`

hopefully this makes sense